# Error displaying the error page: Call to undefined method JAdminCssMenu::addChild()

Tags: update, administration, joomla-3.7, fatal-error

today updated Joomla 3.7.5 on 3.8.0 & I have error:
"Error displaying the error page: Call to undefined method JAdminCssMenu::addChild(): Call to undefined method JAdminCssMenu::addChild()"

Joomla admin panel doesn't work with sections. Can you help me please.

Thanks a lot.

Best regards,
Alex K.

Problem solved. Please, your folders (backup) on local disk (for example: C or D or E disk) upload folders on your FTP. And your admin panel again work last Joomla ver. 3.7.x

[image: Upload on FTP]

Alex K

Comment: i am having the same problem. Can i ask you how did you solve it? Kind regards
Saviour

Comment: I change the folders in the administrator folder. Please careful about your components. I don't have a special configuration as SP Page Builder.

Comment: Dear Saviour, Before Joomla 3.8.0 upgrade - in: Admin panel -> Extension -> Manager extension -> Control -> Configure the filter on the Control Panel !!! -> & please TURN OFF "SP Page Builder Admin Menu"! And everything will work. Now you can upgrade to Joomla 3.8.0.

Comment: More specifically, does anyone know the CAUSE of this change?
I have the same error from a different extension, so cannot just download a patch. In my case, the line that throws the error is $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode(JText::_('REDACTED'), '#'), true);

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue but isn't related to Joomla.

Other people have also ran into the same error, and it's due to **SP Page Builder Pro**

More information can be found on it here: https://www.joomshaper.com/forums/joomla-3-8

Solution: Update **SP Page Builder Pro** to **2.5.3**